# Above Ground Pool - Pinhole Leaks

Tags: leak, pool

Hopefully this is okay to ask here -

I stored my pool for the winter last year and have just got it out and filled up about halfway (3,000 of 6,000 gallons).

I have found 3 pinhole leaks as I have been walking around the pool every few hours as the water level increases. 
I have since patched these and the water has stopped.

Let's just say I hadn't discovered this as its so slow to escape.
Can something like this just tear if people are in the pool playing or am I over thinking this based on the size of it?

I am probably going to retire the pool after this season but so far, this appears to be the only noticeable issues.

Just not sure what 6,000 gallons of water can do on a hole like this. 
Patches seem to be a common thing so I assume they are meant to help solve problems like this.

Just looking for some reassurance I suppose.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First of all- Good on you for patching it rather than dumping it in the landfill!

I had the same pool problem last summer, several pin hole leaks.  What is cool is you can patch them underwater with the patch kit.  (I recommend applying the patches on the water side.)  The real tough ones are holes on the bottom of the pool.  They aren't easy to find without goggles and slowly crawling along the bottom of the pool.  I only found mine when a tiny piece of dirt was being sucked into the leak.

As for an answer, your sides will no suddenly tear because the material on the side is rip stop. (nylon threads embedded in the vinyl).